# A method const with std::future

Tags: c++

I have a class A that has vectors:

```
std::vector < std::shared_ptr<B> > bvec;
std::vector<std::future<void> > futures;
```

Where B is another class.

I have a method:

```
void A::Method() const {
    for (auto&& b : bvec) {
        futures.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, fun));
    }
}
```

Where:

```
void fun(std::shared_ptr<B> b) {
    b->bMethod();
}
```

Since there is that "const" after "A::Method()", I cannot modify future inside that method. Creating a vector locally/globally doesn't help. Is there another way to optimize the for loop inside of the A::Method() without removing "const"?

Comment: Simply remove const.

Comment: There are at least a billion different other ways to optimize that loop.  With no idea of what you are optimizing that loop for, which of the billion+ ways to optimize that loop you should use is unclear.

Comment: Where else is the futures vector used?

Comment: @Kevin It's supposed to be used only in that method.

Comment: Then it should be a local variable. But you said "Creating a vector locally/globally doesn't help" - how did it not help?

Comment: @Kevin it gives me an error:
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF638A100C7 in Program.Release.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000005285AE3000).

Comment: Must be something else. The code you posted does not look like there is a stack overflow.

Comment: That's unrelated to the code you've posted. Your code is getting a stack overflow from using too much stack space.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the const. There is no reason why that function should be const. Lying in your interface is never a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

try setting the future mutable:

`mutable std::vector<std::future<void> > futures;`

shoud do the trick (that said, may not be a good idea on a design stand point, but ths is hard to tell as we know little of your design...)

Comment: It gives me an error:
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF6EFA2FFC7 in Program.Release.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000006A2F0C3000).

Comment: well you have another bug :) mutable is syntaxic suggar, thus wont change runtime behaviour. Try using libsanitizer.

Comment: @OznOg it's possible that some other function assumes that `A::Method` is thread-safe because it is const. By preserving the const qualifier and removing the const-semantics, mutable may as well be the cause of the bug.

Comment: agree, then locking would be necessary (even when removing the const)... but we know really too little about the problem here..